# Group by in javascript or angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, arrays

I just want to do sum value column based on the Year and my data is below, but I don't know how to do this either using angular(in script) or javascript.

```
[
    {"Year":2013,"Product":"A","Value":0},
    {"Year":2013,"Product":"B","Value":20},
    {"Year":2013,"Product":"A","Value":50},
    {"Year":2014,"Product":"D","Value":55},
    {"Year":2014,"Product":"M","Value":23},
    {"Year":2015,"Product":"D","Value":73},
    {"Year":2015,"Product":"A","Value":52},
    {"Year":2016,"Product":"B","Value":65},
    {"Year":2016,"Product":"A","Value":88}
]
```

I want to perform the sum on Value column and remove Product column as well.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit As commenters have pointed out, this doesn't even require Lodash. Been using Lodash so much for current project I forgot `reduce` is built in.** :-)

Also updated to put data in desired form `[{"yyyy" : xxxx},...]`.

This code will accomplish this:

```
var data = [{"Year":2013,"Product":"A","Value":0},{"Year":2013,"Product":"B","Value":20},{"Year":2013,"Product":"A","Value":50},{"Year":2014,"Product":"D","Value":55},{"Year":2014,"Product":"M","Value":23},{"Year":2015,"Product":"D","Value":73},{"Year":2015,"Product":"A","Value":52},{"Year":2016,"Product":"B","Value":65},{"Year":2016,"Product":"A","Value":88}];

var sum = data.reduce(function(res, product){

    if(!(product.Year in res)){
        res[product.Year] = product.Value;
    }else{
        res[product.Year] += product.Value;
    }

    return res;
}, {});

result = [];

for(year in sum){
    var tmp = {};
    tmp[year] = sum[year];
    result.push(tmp);
}

console.log(result);
```

RESULT:

`[{"2013" : 70}, {"2014" : 78}, {"2015" : 125}, {"2016" : 153}]`

---

**ORIGINAL ANSWER**

The easiest way I can think of to do this is with the [Lodash](http://www.lodash.com) Library. It gives you some nice functional programming abilities like `reduce`, which basically applies a function to each element of an array or collection one by one and accumulates the result.

In this case, if you use Lodash, you can accomplish this as follows:

```
var data = [{"Year":2013,"Product":"A","Value":0},{"Year":2013,"Product":"B","Value":20},{"Year":2013,"Product":"A","Value":50},{"Year":2014,"Product":"D","Value":55},{"Year":2014,"Product":"M","Value":23},{"Year":2015,"Product":"D","Value":73},{"Year":2015,"Product":"A","Value":52},{"Year":2016,"Product":"B","Value":65},{"Year":2016,"Product":"A","Value":88}];

result = _.reduce(data, function(res, product){

    if(!(product.Year in res)){
        res[product.Year] = product.Value;
    }else{
        res[product.Year] += product.Value;
    }

    return res;
}, {});
```

This yields:

```
{
   "2013": 70,
   "2014": 78,
   "2015": 125,
   "2016": 153
}
```

Basically, what we're telling Lodash is that we want to go through all the elements in data one by one, performing some operation on each of them. We're going to save the results of this operation in a variable called `res`. Initially, `res` is just an empty object because we haven't done anything. As Lodash looks at each element, it checks if that Product's year is in `res`. If it is, we just add the `Value` to that year in `res`. If it's not, we set that Year in `res` to the `Value` of the current product. This way we add up all the product values for each year.

If you want to try it out you can do it here:
[Online Lodash Tester](https://codepen.io/travist/full/jrBjBz/)

Cheers!

Comment: You can also do this without _lodash_ since `reduce` is a method available on the array.

Comment: This is what I want  [
  { "2013": 70},
   {"2014": 78},
   {"2015": 125},
   {"2016": 153}
]

Comment: @TomekSułkowski you're right. Been using Lodash so much on current project started to forget which functions are built in and which are not.

Comment: @JeelaniKhan added code to do that. Not super elegant, perhaps someone can find better way to transform it into that.

Comment: Can we continue the above and expand the solution to the google trend chart.

Comment: result.splice(0, 0, [{ label: 'SecuredYear', type: 'number' }, { label:'ValueInDhs', type: 'number' }]); google.charts.load("current", { packages: ["corechart"] });google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);function drawChart() {var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([result]);var options =title: 'Age vs. Weight comparison', legend: 'none', crosshair: { trigger: 'both', orientation: 'both' },trendlines: {0: {type: 'polynomial',degree: 3,visibleInLegend: true,}}};var chart = new google.visualization.ScatterChart(document.getElementById('chart_pointSize'));chart.draw(data, options);}

Answer (score 0):

You could do this using plain JavaScript. We use an object that will hold the results and the `forEach` array method. The object that would hold the results would have as keys the years and as values the sums of the corresponding values.

```js
var data = [
    {"Year":2013,"Product":"A","Value":0},
    {"Year":2013,"Product":"B","Value":20},
    {"Year":2013,"Product":"A","Value":50},
    {"Year":2014,"Product":"D","Value":55},
    {"Year":2014,"Product":"M","Value":23},
    {"Year":2015,"Product":"D","Value":73},
    {"Year":2015,"Product":"A","Value":52},
    {"Year":2016,"Product":"B","Value":65},
    {"Year":2016,"Product":"A","Value":88}
];

groupedData = {};

data.forEach(function(item){
    var year = item.Year;
    var value = item.Value;
    if(groupedData.hasOwnProperty(year)){
      groupedData[year]+=value;
    }else{
      groupedData[year]=value;
    }
});

console.log(groupedData);
```

Comment: can we get the result in array of object instead.

Comment: Updated my answer below to do this.

Comment: Yes, actually I am preparing this for the google trend chart and need only year and value with aggregated data based on year.

Comment: Can I ask for the working fidler or something similar

Comment: Can we change the top most code to get the result in [["2013", 70], ["2014" ,78], ["2015" , 125]]